# How do I tell apt to never upgrade a particular package?

Tags: linux, apt

I prefer to install my own version of Firefox. How can I tell apt to never attempt to upgrade it, even if i type "apt-get update ; apt-get upgrade" later?

**Edit:** Okay, so `dpkg -l firefox` prints this:

```
ii  firefox   3.0.3+nobinonly-0ubuntu2   meta package for the popular mozilla web browser
```

So I added this to my prefs:

```
Package: firefox
Pin: version 3.*
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

But apt-get upgrade still prints:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
    (nothing related to firefox)
The following packages will be upgraded:
    (blah blah blah)
    firefox firefox-3.0 firefox-3.0-branding firefox-3.0-gnome-support 
    firefox-gnome-support
    (blah blah blah)
```

I also tried making the package "`*firefox*`", but that didn't work either.

Comment: `sudo apt-mark hold firefox*` works for me (it holds the package at the current installed version)

Answer (score 7):

To put a package to hold:

```
echo "package_name hold"|dpkg --set-selections
```

To 'unhold' it:

```
echo "package_name install"|dpkg --set-selecions
```

To see what your packages on hold are, do an:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the following to /etc/apt/preferences

```
 Package: iceweasel 
 Pin: version 3.0.6*
 Pin-Priority: 1000
```

Comment: So if apt thinks I'm running 3.0, but I'm actually running 3.5, what do I put?

Comment: Use 3.* for the version - the wildcard will match both.

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't seem to be working. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pin the package. Put an entry like this in /etc/apt/preferences. You'll need to adjust the version number etc.

```
Package: mozilla-firefox
Pin: version 1:3.5.*
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

Comment: So if apt thinks I'm running 3.0, but I'm actually running 3.5, what do I put?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at (the complex) section 3.10 of the apt how-to:
http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.en.html.
That may help.