# Maintain old library for compatibility issue in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt

is there a way in Ubuntu to preclude the updater (apt-get) from removing certain obsolete libraries?. For instance to keep libstdc++5.so even when it upgrades to libstdc++6. It happened to me recently and another program started complaining it couldn't find the old lib. (Symlinc is an obvous option, but I'd like to now if there's anything "safer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo 'libstdc++5 hold'|dpkg --set-selections
```

which will prevent that package from being removed/upgraded

Answer (score 1):

libstdc++5 and libstdc++6 are separate packages that don't conflict with one another. You can [pin packages](https://serverfault.com/questions/37868/how-do-i-tell-apt-to-never-upgrade-a-particular-package/37884#37884) to a particular version, but since they're different packages that shouldn't matter in this case.